# Using S3 + Glue + Athena to analyze all events from EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I want to log as many platform produced actions as possible. (Kind of embracing event-sourced architecture but from the other way around). For example, I want to log when and how a *report* was created, or when and how a *contact* was deleted, or when an *agent* logged-in and logged-out.

Since our application tries to use event-based microservices decoupling (using AWS EventBridge) I have figured to just emit events for any actions I want to log. So, for example, an *agent* logged-in, an event is emitted, an *agent* created a report, an event is emitted (you get the idea).

Now I have created a catch-all-events rule that forwards any event to AWS Kinesis firehose. The firehose saves events in batches to the S3 bucket. Now to analyze those JSON events, I run an AWS Glue crawler on the bucket to produce schema. And lastly, I run AWS Athena queries to make sense of all that data I get.

This is the visualization of how events are being analyzed:

[image: Architecture]

Now for you just to understand what kind of events/data can be found in that S3 bucket:

```
{"version":"0","id":"c1d9e9a4-25a2-a0d8-2fa4-b062efec98c4","detail-type":"OneTypeee","source":"OneSource","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:35:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"Key1":"Value1"}}
{"version":"0","id":"c13879a4-2h32-a0d8-9m33-b03jsh3cxxj4","detail-type":"OtherType","source":"SomeMagicSource","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:36:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"Key2":"Value2", "Key22":"Value22"}}
{"version":"0","id":"gi442233-3y44a0d8-9m33-937rjd74jdddj","detail-type":"MoreTypes","source":"SomeMagicSource2","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:45:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"MagicKey":"MagicValue", "Foo":"Bar"}}
```

And there are thousands and thousands of these lines in thousands and thousands of files. And there are hundreds of different types of events that contain different data. They are separated into different folders for the year, month, day, hour (this is done by the Kinesis Firehose).

Now the problem I run into, that every partition gets a slightly different schema and when I try to run Athena SQL queries I get this type of error (this is an example):

Your query has the following error(s):

> HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table
> and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be
> coerced. The column 'detail' in table
> 'xxx-alleventscrawlerdatabase-dev.xxx_allevents_dev' is declared as
> type 'structyes:string,key:string,sum:int', but partition
> 'partition_0=Events2021/partition_1=01/partition_2=17/partition_3=12'
> declared column 'detail' as type 'structkey:string,sum:int'.

I have tried different crawler configurations but with no luck.

**So my questions are:**

1. In general - is this a good approach to log and analyze your events data?
2. How do I have a unified schema that covers all different keys and does not produce HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH exception?

Comment: is it still relevant? maybe you can share the results? I'm trying to do the same as you described - so far I've configured AWS Glue crawler with "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table" checkbox set and I've got auto partitioned table with "detail" row as string, including event details

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, what you can do is delete the table and rerun the crawler. Issue with some partitions have different schema.
That's the quickest way.

Unless you know which partitions causing the issue, you may want to delete those partitions and rerun the crawler.

Answer (score 0):

> hundreds of different types of events that contain different data

I'm assuming when you say "different data" you mean the schema/fields for the `detail` field is different? So hundreds of unique record formats?

My initial reaction is that writing queries for data with that many formats will be tricky.

If you do have that many different schemas, can you have Firehose put the data into separate folders by `event-type` and/or `source`? I don't use Glue much, but I'm assuming it could create a different table for each of your subfolders.

In general--maybe for scenarios with less schemas--one could create a single table where the `detail` field is a string type. You can then have one or more ETL jobs (maybe using [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-insert-into-etl.html)) to move the data into a new table for each event type.

Alternatively, you could go with the single schema approach (`detail` field is a string) and get good at using [JSON functions in Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html). I think it all depends on how complex your analysis is.